# Firebase Cloud Functions – JavaScript/Typescript Promise reject() issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Functions methods like:

```
export const someCallableCloudFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   […]
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      […]
      if (someStatement) {
         resolve("resolveDataString")
      } else {
         reject({ status: "error", code: "429", message: "someErrorMessage" })
      }
   })
})
```

And calling them with:

```
firebase.functions().httpsCallable("someCallableCloudFunction")(/*some args*/)
   .then(data => { /* data = "resolveDataString" */ })
   .catch(error => { /* here's the problem */ })
```

**The issue**: This is what the error looks like in the client which calls the method: `[Error: INTERNAL]`. And this is what the error log looks like in the Firebase Cloud Functions Console (Emulator!):

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "code": "429",
  "message": "Unhandled error",
  "severity": "ERROR"
}
```

`resolve()` works perfectly fine but `reject()` 1) does not print the error object defined in the Cloud Functions method correctly and 2) does not give the error object to the client.  Instead the client receives `[Error: INTERNAL]`.

Do I have to use `resolve()` for both resolve and reject and define statements which can be handled by the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors):

> To ensure the client gets useful error details, return errors from a
> callable by throwing (or returning a Promise rejected with) an
> instance of [`functions.https.HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror).

and

> If an error other than HttpsError is thrown from your functions, your
> client instead receives an error **with the message INTERNAL** and the
> code internal.